# Filter by date based on another parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a report that shows a list of jobs and their current status (open, closed, etc.). The report has a parameter that allows the user to select one or more statuses. Currently my where clause includes JobStatus IN (@Status). I'm now being asked to add a parameter for job closed date. They want to still select one or more statuses, but then also have the option to specify a closed job date range. Therefore, there could be a need to display all open jobs and also closed jobs within a specific date range. Note: Closed date is a field within the table. How do I modify my where clause to support this?

Comment: So if a closed date is specified.. you want to see all open jobs as well as jobs closed at or before that date or ONLY on that date? Likewise.. if no date is specified, you want to see all closed and or open jobs depending on @status? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a condition in your query based on JobStatus.
If the status is not closed it ignores the ClosedDate.

Your where clause could be like the one below

```
WHERE JobStatus IN (@Status)
    AND (
        JobStatus <> 'Closed'
        OR (
            JobStatus = 'Closed'
            AND ClosedDate BETWEEN @FromDate
                AND @ToDate
            )
        )
```